# How to use environment variables in tafj.properties for standalone TAFJ

Tags: jbase

Is there a way to use environment variables in the tafj.properties setup file when running standalone Temenos TAFJ? I want to configure few things outside the tafj.properties so it can be easily changed without the modification of the tafj.properties file itself.
I know that this file will pickup the TAFJ_HOME environment variable if it is initialized, but I would also like to parametrize DB connection URL, password and other things, so they are not stored as text inside tafj.properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify using the command line arguments, TAFJ will accept these command line arguments.

For example, pass variables with -D option as java command line parameters (%JAVA_OPTS% environment variable is sometimes used by scripts):

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dtemn.tafj.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/r18
```

Comment: Can you give an example how to do it? Would command line arguments be added in tRun or as java arguments?

Comment: It is java style command line with -d, I guess it should work with JAVA_OPTS but not 100% sure. 
If you work in Temenos then definitely TAFJ guy will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the JAVA_OPTS environment variable is overwritten by the tafj_conf script, but after tweeking the startup scripts I was able to accopmlish the task.